# Rails 3 / paperclip: How to get/set attributes of user-submitted mp3 file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a Rails app where users can submit mp3 files to be uploaded. I want to set Ruby object attributes on them as they are uploaded. TagLib lets me grab metadata easily, and locally I can make that work fine, but I'm struggling to find out how to access the object before saving it to Amazon S3. Paperclip *says* that the objects are kept in memory until you .save them.

Where do attachments get stored before saving, and how do I access them? The path attribute on the model is the place where paperclip *will* store the file, future tense, on S3.

For reference, I'm trying to run a `before_[attachment name]_post_process` filter on my sound files to grab the length in seconds of the file and set that as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this in [the Paperclip docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/index) (if you can, please let me know), but it turns out the name of the attachment as specified in your model class is the object. With [TagLib](http://rubydoc.info/gems/taglib-ruby/TagLib/FileRef), you access a sound's properties, before save, as follows:

```
# app/models/sound.rb

    …code…

    has_attached_file :soundfile
             vv same name ^^
    before_soundfile_post_process :set_song_attrs

    …code…

    def set_song_attrs
      TagLib::FileRef.open(soundfile.queued_for_write[:original].path) do |file| 
        self.length = file.audio_properties.length
        self.artist = file.tag.artist
      end 
    end
```